# How to read Images and their text labels (Yolov5 format) in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, text-files, pytorch-dataloader

I am begiiner in image processing and in Pytorch. I have a dataset in Yolov5 formate which consists of 1300 training images and 1300 labels
txt files. I have successfully reads all images in pytorch.

**directory**

```
Images_path='E:\Moving_Train/train/images'
labels_path="E:\Moving_Train\train\labels"
```

**image transformation**

```
train_trasnforms=transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224,224)),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomRotation(10),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    
    ])
```

**custom Dataset class**

```
class dataSets(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root, transform):
        self.files=[]
        self.itemslist=os.listdir(root)
        for i in range(0,len(os.listdir(root))-1,1):
            arr=[]
            arr.append(self.itemslist[i])
            arr.append(self.itemslist[i+1])
            self.files.append(arr)
            #print(arr)

        self.root= root
        self.transform=transform
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.files)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        
        imagepath= os.path.join(self.root, self.files[index][0])
        image=Image.open(imagepath)
        transformedImage=self.transform(image)
    
        imagepath= os.path.join(self.root, self.files[index][1])
        image=Image.open(imagepath)
        transformedImage1=self.transform(image)

        return transformedImage, transformedImage
    

train_dataset = dataSets(Images_path, train_trasnforms)
x= train_dataset.__getitem__(0)
```

**Show images**

```
def show_tranformed_images(dataSet):
    loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataSet, batch_size=6, shuffle=True)
    batch=next(iter(loader))
    images=batch
    images, images2= batch
    
show_tranformed_images(train_dataset)
```

I want some logics to get all these txt lables files within this piece of code.

Comment: if you defined `__getitem__` then you can use `[0]` instead of `.__getitem__(0)` - `train_dataset[0]` instead of `train_dataset.__getitem__(0)`

Comment: you have `self.itemslist = os.listdir(root)` so you could use `len(self.itemslist)` instead of `len(os.listdir(root))`. BTW: `listdir()` may gives names in random order so sometimes it safer to use `list( sorted(os.listdir(root)) )` to get sorted names.

Comment: You can't use the same variables to keep two images. You have to use `transformedImage_1 = ...` and `transformedImage_2 = ...` and `return transformedImage_1, transformedImage_2` because at this moment you return second image two times.

Comment: char \  has special meaning in string (`'\n'`, `'\t'`, `\Uxxxx`, etc.) - even in string with path - so better use `"E:/..."` instead of `"E:\..."` or use double \\ like `"E:\\Moving_Train\\train\\images"` or use prefix `r` for `raw string` like `r"E:\Moving_Train\train\images"`

Comment: I have no idea what format has text file but you should do similar to image - first `sorted(os.listdir(folder))` and next `fh = open(os.path.join(folder, filename)` and `text = fh.read()`. If images and text files have the same names then `sorted()` should gives filenames in the same order and later you can use `zip(all_images, all_text)` to create list with pairs `(image, text)` or you can use the same index to get from two lists `all_images[index]`, `all_text[index]`

Comment: Great @furas Both images and their lables have exactly same name. Every txt labels file has this type of data "0 0.5432692307692307 0.4411057692307692 0.6225961538461539 0.6334134615384616". Both images and labels files are in the different folders.

Comment: as I said before `listdir`, and `for`-loop with `open`, `read`. It may need also `split(" ")` and `for`-loop to convert every string to `float`